# problem with xsane after upgrading to 23.04

Tags: scanner, xsane, 23.04

I had been using xsane with no problems until I upgraded to v. 23.04 of Ubuntu. It loads, the scanner scans, but xsane presents a blank page. If I enter the command xsane in the terminal, I get the error message "Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module". This module is installed, some other problem must have been introduced by the upgrade

Comment: welcome to the joys of interim releases